# Using Metadata for childtheme content input - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I am using metadata inside of a childtheme on wordpress to make custom content boxes. We had some of it working but could never get the whole thing up and running and now none of it is working.

Background: we use one template for 7 different pages that all need the same layout just different content that is changed by editors within the company.

Examples:

Here is some of our options php file where it adds the metaboxes.

```
wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'undergrad_nonce' );
global $post;
$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'undergrad', true);

?>

<label for="undergrad-HighlightImage"><?php _e( "Highlight Image", 'example' ); ?></label>
<br />
<textarea rows="6" class="widefat" type="text" name="undergrad-HighlightImage" id="undergrad-HighlightImage" value="" size="30"><?php if(isset($data['HighlightImage'])) echo esc_attr($data['HighlightImage'])?></textarea>
```

We know this works because it appears in the admin console and saved to our db. As you can see this input here here (site and image info was removed):

```
a:8:{s:14:"HighlightImage";s:71:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.wp-content/uploads/2017/06/xxxxxxxxxx.png"
```

And here is one of the functions we use in our template page to call the metadata:

```
add_action('genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'add_undergrad_Highlight', 1);

function add_undergrad_Highlight(){

global $post;
global $meta;


echo'<div id="highlightBox">';

if(isset($meta['HighlightImage'])){
    $HighlightImage = '<img src="';
    $HighlightImage .= $meta['HighlightImage'];
    $HighlightImage .= '"/>';
}

if(isset($meta['HighlightImage'])){
    echo $HighlightImage;
}

echo'</div>';
```

}

My question is why will it not pull our metadata? It was at first but then when we added the rest of the boxes what we had would no longer pull?

Note: please do not ask for site or any information that may disclose the identity of the company, last time I posed a question within a couple days we began seeing attempted code injection, priv esc, and many other attacks, about 1000 per every three minutes of failed attempts against our secondary firewalls. This may be coincidental but I don't want to take chances that malicious people use this site for targeting.

Comment: I found a partial solution. For some reason global $meta isn't parsing the information from the db. I used:
 `$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'undergrad', true);`

to get the data into an array of parsed data then used 

    `if(isset($data['HighlightImage'])){
  $HighlightImage = '<img src="';
     $HighlightImage .= $data['HighlightImage'];
     $HighlightImage .= '"/>';
 }`

However, This will only work for the very metadata title and content. I cannot parse through the rest